# Make jQuery selector more succinct

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any way to express the following jQuery selector more succinctly?

```
$this
.children('div[name][class="array"],div[name][class="object"],input[name][value]')
.each( ... );
```

Roughly speaking, what this selector does is pick the immediate children of `$this` that satisfy the following logical condition:

```
('div' AND '[name]' AND '[class="array"]')
OR
('div' AND '[name]' AND '[class="object"]')
OR
('input' AND '[name]' AND '[value]')
```

I would like to have a selector that picks the immediate children of `$this` that satisfy the following equivalent logical condition:

```
'[name]' AND (('input' AND '[value]') OR
              ('div' AND ('[class="array"]' OR '[class="object"]')))
```

And no, I do **NOT** want to make successive calls to `.filter()`.

Comment: That's not a horribly verbose selector, so I don't see why it can't be left how it is. AFAIK, there's not a much simpler way to express something like that.

Comment: Not horribly verbose? The `.children(...)` line is more than 50 characters wide.

Comment: it may be >50 characters, but it's not 'horribly verbose' in that it appears to be as succinct as possible already.

Comment: I wish this were possible: `$('[name]:or(input[value],div:or(.array,.object))')`. Not only it would be more succinct. Its evaluation would be more efficient, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this.children("input[value][name], div.array[name], div.object[name]")
```

Comment: Missed that, but from a logical point of view, that selector still evaluates the first condition.